# Error while converting Mongodb Date to Java Date

Tags: java, json, mongodb, gson

I am getting this JSON from mongoDB

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("4f95bbe3742b1eaa929b81ef"), 
  "empNo" : NumberLong(10), 
  "empName" : "abc", 
  "joinDate" : ISODate("2012-04-23T20:30:27.421Z"), 
  "address" : {
    "addNo" : NumberLong(1), 
    "addLocation" : "add0", 
    "street" : { 
      "sNo" : NumberLong(10), 
      "sName" : "Street 1" 
    } 
  } 
}
```

I want to convert `ISODate("2012-04-23T20:30:27.421Z")` to Java Date.

I am getting an error while converting the JSON to Object using Google's Gson Library when Date Atribute is there.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Try to convert string with gson after that use jodatime to be able to convert Java util Date format.

Answer (score 3):

Mongo date is a ISO formatted. You can use `ISODateTimeFormat` of  [Joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library to convert ISO date string to java data object.

Check out [converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date) for more info